# install old package R

Tags: r, dplyr, package

i'm working in Rstudio version 0.98.507.0 and R 3.1.1. **I'm working in a virtual machine, i can not install anything in the computer (professional computer and it's take so long to get authorization for new installation)**

i'm looking to install package "*plotly*" but this package require "*dplyr*" to work; The current version of "*dplyr*" is only working with R version 3.1.2

as well i'm trying to install an older version of "dplyr but nothing works.
i downloaded the files from cran. i put the file in the directory and here are the code i have tryied and the error message i got:

1)

```
install.packages("J:/ PATH TO THE FILE/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")
```

the error is:

```
   Warning: invalid package 'J:/ PATH/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz'
 Error: ERROR: no packages specified
 Warning in install.packages :
 running command '"Q:/R.001/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\I0368711\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "J:/PATH/R/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
 Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘J:/PATH/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

2)
Then i tried to set the working directory, and i run

```
install.packages("dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")
```

the error message is

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
 UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.
PATH TO THE FILE
 Warning: invalid package 'dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz'
 Error: ERROR: no packages specified
 Warning in install.packages :
 running command '"Q:/R.001/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\I0368711\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
 Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
 Warning in install.packages :
 running command '"Q:/R.001/R-31~1.1/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\I0368711\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
 Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

3)
i tried another solution:

```
install_version("dplyr", version = "0.7.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

the error message is:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(value) : 
  do not know how to convert 'value' to class “POSIXct”
```

4)
the last solution i tried is:

```
 path<- "https:/cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(path, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

but it doesnt work too..

I really have no idea of what else i could do to try to install this packages..

sorry for my bad level in English, i made my best to create an understandable topic..

Thanks for the help

EDIT:

5)

```
path<- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(path, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

i have the message

```
trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz'
```

but nothing happend and after 5 minutes I decide to close the programme

6)

```
install.packages("file://J:PATH/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")
```

i got the same error messager than 1.

because i got an old R version, i tryied to install dplyr version 0.1, created in 2014, but it doesnt work as well.
i tryied to install the package manually in my personnal computer, to see if i'm doing something wrong, and solution 6 is working in my computer (solution 5 didnt)

Answer (score 5):

From `?install.packages`:

> (‘http://’ and ‘file://’ URLs are also accepted and the files
>             will be downloaded and installed from local copies.)

So your last attempt was pretty close:

```
path<- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"
#             ^^
install.packages(path, repos=NULL, type="source")
#                ^^^^
```

This will work if you have all dependencies already installed locally. Also your first attempts should have worked if you had used `file://J:/...`.

Another possibility for getting older packages is to use an appropriate MRAN snapshot. For example, if I download the docker image `rocker/r-ver:3.3.3` then `https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-04-21` is used as repository.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried the 2 first solution and it's still not working. i'll take a look at your last solution tomorrow because i'm nnot enough experimented with R to understand whats exactly is a MRAN snapshot, but i'm sure i'll find enough information to understand. Just to be sure, i do not have to unzip my  tag.gz file?

Comment: @remikerkour You do not have to unzip the `.tar.gz` file. Could you update the question with the error messages from the new attempts?

Answer (score 3):

okay! So i found a way

the code to run the installation from cran website is

```
path<- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.7.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(path, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

***There is no S at http***

i still have huge problem about dependencie to install my package but i think i'll be able to solve them. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ok, old version of R might have problems with HTTPS, so using HTTP is a good idea.