# Install older R packages BINS

Tags: r, package

I'd like to install the package reticulate 1.16, but cannot build from source as I am in a containerized environment over which I have no control.
I was able to locate the source tar.gz files on CRAN as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800215/install-old-package-r)

```
install.packages(cranurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

however is there a way to install packages not from source, like what `install.packages` does for current versions?

I would be after something using only `install.packages`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use devtools to install older versions of packages from CRAN. It's explained [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages).

You would use

```
require(devtools)
install_version("reticulate", version = "1.16")
```

Alternatively, using the CRAN URL for a specific version you can do.

```
install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/reticulate/reticulate_1.16.tar.gz', repo=NULL, type='source')
```

Comment: I would be after something using only `install.packages`

Comment: Then the 2nd option is the one you want :)

Comment: I can't install from source, please read the question

Comment: Sorry, then I don't think I understand your question. What do you mean by "install from source"?

Comment: what you suggest is using tyoe = source. I cant use that, i need to use the same method as normal install packages...

Comment: Documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages) mentions that source is the default except for Windows and some macOS builds. What OS is your container using?

Comment: Ubuntu. basically I can only use "install.packages()" as a dockerfile instructions. Seems weird that source is the only method available to install older versions...

Comment: Based on the documentation source will be the default way on Ubuntu even for the latest versions, so I'm not sure how to get around that.